# Carousel de Bootstrap con múltiples imágenes y Angular ng-resource

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de crear un *carousel* de `Bootstrap` que carga múltiples imágenes mediante una `api rest`. Cuando lo pruebo estáticamente me da el resultado de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando mando a llamar los datos desde `Angular` para consumir la `api` sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código del *carousel*:

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="1000" id="hbo_mas">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item " ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="data in datos">

            <div class="col-md-3">

                <a> <img src="{{ data.ruta }}{{ data.nombre }}.jpg"></a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

y el `script`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function () {

        var next = $(this).next();

        if (!next.length) {

            next = $(this).siblings(':first');

        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            next = next.next();

            if (!next.length) {

                next = $(this).siblings(':first');

            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        }

    });

});
```

No sé dónde pueda estar el error. Gracias.

Comment: no es la misma http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17705/slick-carusel-angular-con-imagenes-multiples-almacenadas-en-api-rest ???

Answer (score 1):

Si sirve de referencia, este es mi código para la `api`:

```
angularRoutingApp.controller("ruta_hbo_max", function ($scope, $http, dataResource) {

    $http.get("http://192.168.100.15/api/hbo_max").success(function (data) {

        $scope.datos = data;

    });

    $scope.datosResource = dataResource.get();

});

angularRoutingApp.factory("dataResource", function ($resource) {

    return $resource("http://192.168.100.15/api/hbo_max", //la url donde queremos consumir
           {},
           { get: { method: "GET", isArray: true }
    });

});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías porfavor explicar al _OP_ lo que hace tu código? Así en un futuro, personas con el mismo problema sepan que hacer al entender tu código!

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de César Gómez, pero como no sabemos cómo es el objeto `data` no es seguro que `$index` funcione. Intenta hacer el `track by data.nombre` si estás seguro que que es imposible que se repita.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="1000" id="hbo_mas">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item " ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="data in datos track by data.nombre">

            <div class="col-md-3">

                <a> <img src="{{ data.ruta }}{{ data.nombre }}.jpg"></a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos. Pude resolverlo dejando mi `script` de `jQuery` de la siguiente manera. Pero ahora mi problema es que funciona en `Firefox` y en `Explorer` pero en `Chrome` me los sigue mostrando de uno en uno. ¿Qué podría ser?
De antemano, gracias por su atención.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".item").each(function () {

        var next = $(this).next();

        if (!next.length) {

            next = $(this).siblings(":first");

        }

        next.children(":first-child").clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            next = next.next();

            if (!next.length) {

                next = $(this).siblings(":first");

            }

            next.children(":first-child").clone().appendTo($(this));

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Recuerda que cuando haces un `ng-repeat`, debes diferenciar cada elemento cargado para que `AngularJS` sepa que es distinto. Puedes colocar un `track by $index` para que puedan cargar correctamente todas las imágenes.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="1000" id="hbo_mas">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item " ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="data in datos track by $index">

            <div class="col-md-3">

                <a><img src="{{ data.ruta }}{{ data.nombre }}.jpg"></a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: probe agregandole la linea pero sigo opteniendo el mismo resultado