# Slick carusel angular con imagenes multiples almacenadas en api rest

Tags: angularjs, json, api

Estoy tatatando de hacer un carusel usando slick carusel con multiples imagenes que estan guardadas en una base de datos y las mando traer por medio de una api rest pero cuando lo ejecuto no me hace el carrusel sino que solo me  muestra las imagenes

asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la vista

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="slick.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick.css"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <slick infinite="true" slides-to-show="3" slides-to-scroll="3"  init-onload=true>
    <div ng-class  ng-repeat="image in images">
      <img ng-src="{{image.ruta}}">
    </div>
    </slick>
  </body>
</html>
```

y este el controlador:

```
var app = angular.module('demo',['slick','ngResource']);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.images = [];

  $http.get('http://192.168.100.15/api/hbo_max').success(function(data) 
  {
    $scope.images = data;
  })
  .error(function() {
      alert("error");
    })
});
```

nose que pueda estar mal ojala alguien pudiera ayudarme por su atencion gracias

Comment: no es la misma http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17440/carusel-de-bootstrap-multiples-imagenes-angular-ngresource ???

Comment: en una trato con el carusel de bootstrap y en otra con slick